# How to sign in users to Firebase with Google Plus Sign-In

Tags: authentication, google-plus, firebase

I like to use Google Plus Sign for authentification in FireBase.

The signinCallback of Google Plus returns a auth object.
How can I use this information to sign in my users securely to FireBase?

Auth auth object looks like:

```
access_token: "ya29.2342324234"
authuser: "0"
client_id: "23ss4443234"
code: "4/tLijpRBvHp9hDNc-hcZk00bqvpz4.2342342"
cookie_policy: "single_host_origin"
expires_at: "136334897186"
expires_in: "3600"
g-oauth-window: Window
g_user_cookie_policy: "single_host_origin"
id_token: "324234234234.234234234.bW--234234---E2-Hj1I"
issued_at: "1364893586"
prompt: "consent"
scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
session_state: "234234234234234234..32cd"
state: ""
token_type: "Bearer"
```

Comment: One good solution is to check out [Singly](http://singly.com/), which provides Firebase auth as a service. Otherwise you'll need to roll your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can integrate any auth system with Firebase using custom auth tokens. See:
https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/custom-login.html

Firebase has a service called Firebase Simple Login service that makes it easy to handle some common auth scenarios. However, it doesn't handle Google Plus authentication. Instead, you could check out our third party integration with Singly:
https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/authentication.html

Comment: Are there any near term plans to add Google authentication to firebase simple login? It would be really desirable, and especially so, given  android's leading position.

Comment: @Jarnal - Firebase now supports Google auth.