# Google Sign-in for Unity without Google+?

Tags: authentication, unity-game-engine, oauth, google-play-games

I'm developing an application in Unity, primarily focusing on iOS right now.
For the backend, I decided to try out firebase since they have a Unity package and so far its been pretty painless.

Does a Google Signin option exist for Unity that doesnt involve GooglePlayGames (GPG)?
I'm not interested in integrating to that platform at all, Im really just after the Sign in feature so I can grab the user token and authenticate to Firebase. 
I currently have GPG and Firebase up and running...and it works great.
My issue is that if a user is not a Google+ member, they cant authenticate since apparently GPG relies heavy on that. 
All I'm really after is a solution for vanilla Google Login that would give me an auth token I can use in Firebase...

If you're familiar with Pokemon Go...a very similar login flow.
With that app i was able to use a google account that doesnt have google+ and everything worked fine.

Comment: Try to check this [Github](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity) if it can help you in your case. It is a Google Play Games plugin for Unity allows you to access the Google Play Games API through Unity's social interface. For more information, check this [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760317/how-to-sign-in-users-to-firebase-with-google-plus-sign-in) that says that Firebase doesn't handle Google Plus authentication.

Comment: Yes, you can use [Google Sign In](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-signin-unity/releases) Unity plugin to login to your Unity App. Here is a [quick sample from Git](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-signin-unity). Also you check [SocialLogin](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/79450) asset from Unity Store, it support Google, Twitter and Facebook with full guideline.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, don't use the Google Play games plugin; it doesn't work for iOS anyways if you don't have an existing Google Play games account via any Android device usage in past. Even for many Android users Play Games apps won't work because it's not packaged with every Android device.

However, I am using this Google Login Unity plugin in iOS & Android which is available in the Asset Store. It works really well.

https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/content/94517